# Services not responding inside controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I am very new to angularjs .I am stuck in getting local json data into controller

Here is .js file :

```
'use strict';

angular.module('angularPlaygroundApp').factory('campaignService', function($http) {
  return $http.get('data/campaign.json');
})
.controller('CampaignCtrl', function ($scope, campaignService) {
    $scope.name  = '';
    campaignService.success(function(data){
      console.log('check');
      $scope.name = data.compaigns;
      console.log(data);
    });
  });
```

Even console.log inside controller not giving response .

Let me know if I am making some mistake .

You can see my directory structure here
[image: You can watch my directory structure here]

Comment: See you browser console, there maybe some issue with the service call. You can also add a failure callback function `error` and see if the call is going to error callback.

Comment: Yeah you are right  :   error function works  means its not getting json data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an object inside your factory declaration and return that.

```
angular.module('angularPlaygroundApp').factory('campaignService', function($http) {
  var fact = {};
  fact.getData = function() {
    return $http.get('data/campaign.json');
  };

  return fact;
})
```

Inside your controller, you'd use

```
campaignService.getData()....
```

Here's the entire code (you had an error in the module decrlaration also):

campaign.json (copied some array code off wikipedia):

```
    {
    "campaigns": 
        [
        { "type": "home", "number": "212 555-1234" },
        { "type": "office",  "number": "646 555-4567" }
    ]
}
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="angularPlaygroundApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body >
    <script src= "angular.js"></script>

    <script src= "script.js"></script>

    <div ng-controller='CampaignCtrl'>
        {{name}}
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
angular.module('angularPlaygroundApp', [])

.factory('campaignService', function($http) {
  var fact = {};
  fact.getData = function() {
    return $http.get('data/campaign.json');
  };

  return fact;
})

.controller('CampaignCtrl', function ($scope, campaignService) {
    $scope.name  = [];

    campaignService.getData()
    .success(function(data){
      $scope.name = data.campaigns;
      console.log(data);
    })
    .error(function(data) {
      console.log('error');
    });

  });
```

Comment: how to use that in controller  :   campaignService.success is giving error on console ?

Comment: You'd have to use 
campaignService.getData().success(...).error(...)

Comment: I've updated my response to include the updated code. The console prints out the array from the json file. You should be able to use it to pretty much get to whatever you need to do now.

Comment: Still its calling error method  :  error . What can be possible reason ?

Comment: Is there any other error message given in the console or just the error message you've put in your code? Are you running from web server? When I don't run from web server, I get a cross-origin error.
Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

Comment: I am using grunt serve to run it :  bower , npm setup . console.log('error')  is printing  not success one

Comment: That is weird. While this might not help, can you confirm that the files angular.js, index.html & script.js are in the same folder and that the file campaign.json is in a sub-folder named data?

Comment: hmm , that is in different folder

Comment: I've updated the code to include the correct json format and also display the relevant variable in the html file. I doubt this would also help since things worked fine for me before also but can you give this also a try?

Comment: you can see my directory structure.  I have added my window screen

Comment: Please look at your module declaration. I have already indicated above that there is an error in your module declaration. You have forgotten the 2nd parameter to it... an array of all the dependencies. Since you don't have any dependencies, it should be an empty array.
`angular.module('angularPlaygroundApp', [])`

Comment: Can you please try creating the files as mentioned in my post above and see if that works?

Comment: Thanks for  your time .....It is running now  , actually localhost was not getting campaign.json file